# How do I measure mercury in a graduated cylinder?

Tags: measurements, liquid

Convention says to measure at the bottom of the meniscus, but I think the cohesion/adhesion balance of mercury results in it "bulging out"

Do you measure at the top of the bulge  (near the center) or the bottom (near the edges)?

Comment: Citation for "convention says to..."  please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to measure from the top of mercury column, in tubes that are wide enough to allow a flat area of mercury on top and ignore the lower level along the perimeter where mercury is repelled by glass.

This page has enough detailed instruction on calibration of barometers. [Green river U link.](http://www.instruction.greenriver.edu/kmarr/Chem%20161/Instrument-%20Glassware%20Videos/How%20to%20Zero%20and%20Read%20a%20Barometer/How%20to%20zero%20and%20read%20a%20barometer.htm)